# Send cookie and API Key on the fetch request

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch-api

I am sending a GET request to an API.
The browser **must send a cookie and an API Key on the fetch request**.

The problem that I face is the following:

1. If I send the request without the API Key on header, the **cookie is sent on the request**:

```
fetch(urlToRequest, {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include"
})
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch ((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

2. If I include the Header with API Key, the **cookie is not send on the request**:

```
fetch(urlToRequest, {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {"api-key": apiKey}
})
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch ((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Is this behave normal? Shouldn't the browser send the cookie and the API key as well?

Answer (score 0):

it's a Chrome problem,in some cases Chrome debugger do not show the cookie. The cookie has been sent i think.